# When a Golang program is terminated whilst making a database transaction, can it roll back?

Tags: mysql, go, transactions

Assuming a MariaDB compatible database (AWS Aurora RDS) with default settings, which includes **autocommit enabled**, if a Lambda function was terminated after **three seconds** doing a transaction that takes more than **five seconds**, e.g.

```
  tx, err := h.db.Begin()
  if err != nil {
      log.WithError(err).Error("failed to start transaction")
  }
  res, execErr := tx.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE testtable SET val = %d WHERE id = 1; SELECT SLEEP(5.5);", time.Now().Unix()))
  if execErr != nil {
      log.WithError(err).Error("rolling back")
      err = tx.Rollback()
      if err != nil {
          log.WithError(err).Error("failed to roll back")
      }
  }
  if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
      log.WithError(err).Error("failed to commit")
  }
```

What would one assume the result to be? The transaction would have not been committed?

I am using Go MySQL Driver v1.3.0-84-g6be42e0 btw. I also made a [video showing my results](https://media.dev.unee-t.com/2018-12-04/f58ae28.mp4), but I am wondering if it is right since I don't understand how the [driver could have executed rollback](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/transaction.go#L28).

Comment: `autocommit` is only taken into account if you have not started the transaction explicitly. As soon as you used `BEGIN` - then the only way it to be committed is after an explicit `COMMIT`. As soon as your transaction is in the progress and the connection has been closed - it would be rolled back automatically by the server.

Comment: Ok, so once the COMMIT runs, the transaction runs including the 5.5s sleep. If it gets terminated after 3s, how does it rollback? Should it rollback ?

Comment: If `COMMIT` returned with no errors - it's committed.

Comment: It will roll back, but not from go - the mysql server will see the connection was lost / exceeded a timeout, and roll it back automatically

Comment: Even after a very short space of time? <1s ?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction SQL does not commit. What I believe happens with a <= 5s timeout:

1. BEGINs transaction
2. Executes the SQL synchronously
3. MySQLd detects the client disconnected via a **TCP FIN**
4. MySQLd automatically rolls back since it doesn't see the Commit

### A tweet reply from one of the [Golang MySQL driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) maintainers:

mysqld receives TCP FIN packet when Go client is terminated.
Even though Go client exits uncleanly, OS (Linux kernel, etc) sends TCP FIN or TCP RST.  So mysqld can know client is gone.— INADA Naoki (@methane) [December 4, 2018](https://twitter.com/methane/status/1069825283857952768?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Comment: Note that there's still a chance the transaction will have been completed, if the Go program exits between sending 'COMMIT', and receiving/processing the response. There is never any way to avoid this, so it's still best to make the transactions as idempotent (or recoverable) as possible.

Comment: @Flimzy However, the transaction should be committed independently by the RDBMS upon receipt of 'COMMIT', regardless whether the client is still connected or not, shouldn’t it? If it is: Just as planned! ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Yes, but you cannot rely on your client getting that message. That won't matter in some cases, in others it will.

Answer (score 0):

If you use InnoDB tables, read this from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transactions-life-cycle.html:

> When a connection is closed, the current normal transaction, if any, is rolled back.

This works the same with the Go client, Java client, PHP client, or any other client.

If you use MyISAM tables, there's no rollback. If you have a SQL update currently executing, it may update some subset of the rows, and leave the rest unchanged. You'll end up with a table in an inconsistent state. There is no ACID behavior with non-transactional tables. **This is why you should not use MyISAM.**

Comment: Aurora does not support MyISAM, though interesting nonetheless ! https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

Comment: That's good that Aurora doesn't support MyISAM. But that makes it not really MySQL/MariaDB compatible.